# export to csv powershell script using multiple foreach statements

Tags: powershell

I have following powershell script reading from csv and exporting to another csv. It's working in terms of basic functionality. Script below is currently exporting as such:

| USERS |
| --- |
| jdoe |
| mprice |
| tsmith |

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# csv file name
[parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$CsvFilePath = ".\AllSiteCollectionsLocal.csv"
$csvItems = Import-Csv $CsvFilePath
$resultsarray = @()
$firstObject = New-Object PSObject

# iterate lines in csv
foreach($Item in $csvItems)
{   
    $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($Item.SiteCollection)
    $web = $site.openweb()
    $siteUsers = $web.SiteUsers
    Write-Host $Item.SiteCollection -ForegroundColor Green
    
    foreach($user in $siteUsers)
    {
        Write-Host $user.LoginName
        
        $loginnames = @{
            USERS = $user.LoginName
        }
        $resultsarray += New-Object PSObject -Property $loginnames
    }
    $web.Dispose()
    $site.Dispose()
    $resultsarray | export-csv -Path c:\temp\sitesandusers.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I need to export as below. Note, I dont even need a header, but do need $Item.SiteCollection value to print out between each iteration of users under each site, so the outer foreach needs to print $Item.SiteCollection then the inner foreach would print $user.LoginName

|  |
| --- |
| http://test1.com |
| jdoe |
| mprice |
| http://test2.com |
| tsmith |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you wanted to do parameters for your script to be called from elsewhere? As of now, your metadata attribute on `$CsvFilePath` are redundant to what PowerShell already does for you.

As for your question, you would just have to append `$Item.SiteCollection` to your `PSObject`. This too isn't needed as PowerShell streaming capabilities allow you to assign directly to a variable; so no need for `+=` - *which can be computationally expensive on larger lists slowing overall performance*. Now we end up with:

```
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$CsvFilePath = ".\AllSiteCollectionsLocal.csv"
) 
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$csvItems = Import-Csv $CsvFilePath
$variable = foreach($Item in $csvItems)
{   
    $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($Item.SiteCollection)
    $web  = $site.openweb()
    $siteUsers = $web.SiteUsers
    Write-Host -Object $Item.SiteCollection -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Output -InputObject $Item.SiteCollection
    
    foreach($user in $siteUsers)
    {
        Write-Host -Object $user.LoginName
        Write-Output -InputObject $user.LoginName
    }
    $null = $web.Dispose()
    $null = $site.Dispose()
}
$variable | Out-File -FilePath 'c:\temp\sitesandusers.csv'
```

Bypassing `$variable` you can assign the output directly to the file placing the export outside the first `foreach` statement.

- This requires the use of a sub-expression operator `$()` to wrap around the loop.
- Also added a `Param ( )` statement for your parameter declaration.

  - *Didn't mess with the parameter attributes as it can show the Authors intentions regardless if it's needed or not*.

Probably should add that, `Write-Output` will explicitly write to the success stream allowing the values to be assigned to the variable, whereas `Write-Host` writes to the information stream, so no object pollution (*duplicates*) occur.